# Flink CEP with files and no streams?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

I am trying to use CEP of Flink for log files (as batch job), but not for  streams (as realtime). Is that possible ? If yes, do you know examples Scala codes about that ?

Answer (score 0):

Flink's DataStream API and associated libraries, including the CEP library, can be used on bounded, historic (batch) datasets or with unbounded, live streams -- it makes no difference. Just [setup a file (or directory) as the data source](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sources) and use CEP normally. For correct, reproducible results, you should work in [event time](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/event_time.html) (assuming time plays a role in your processing). This is important, because CEP wants to sort your input stream(s) according to event time -- notions of *before* and *after* should be relative to when the events occured, not when they were processed.

A bit of googling will lead you to some CEP examples. There's a simple example (in Java and Scala) in the [Flink training](http://training.data-artisans.com/exercises/CEP.html) ([github](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/exercises/datastream_scala/cep/LongRides.scala)).